# Calling document viewer from an html viewer

Tags: ubuntu-touch, pdf, html

I have this call to webapp-container in this .desktop file.

```
$ cat .local/share/applications/foo.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=web container
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/webapp-container --enable-addressbar --enable-back-forward --webappUrlPatterns=/home/phablet/*/*/* /home/phablet/*/* /home/phablet/* /home/phablet/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/32/add.svg
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

This is the way I've found to open my local html files. It works fine until I follow a link to a PDF file. Then, I choose Document Viewer to open the PDF file, but it opens a dialog to choose a file to open instead. Sometimes it works right... Why?

Comment: There is a bug in Document viewer, if you don't have Document viewer already open, files don't open from another app. Are you facing the same issue?

Comment: You may be right, pomsky. Anyway, it does not always fail when still not running.